# In PyTorch, what is the input into nll_loss?

Tags: python, pytorch

I am looking at the tutorial here: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/fgsm_tutorial.html

```
import torch.nn.functional as F
loss = F.nll_loss(output, target)
```

In the above two lines of code, what exactly is "target"? They load the data set for target but never discuss what it is exactly. The documentation is also hard to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check yourself by running below code:

```
test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    datasets.MNIST('../data', train=False, download=True, transform=transforms.Compose([
            transforms.ToTensor(),
            ])),
        batch_size=1, shuffle=True)
for data, target in test_loader:
    print(data, target)
    break
```

Here, `data` is basically a grayscaled MNIST image and `target` is the label between `0` and `9`.

So, in `loss = F.nll_loss(output, target)`, `output` is the model prediction(what the model predicted on giving an image/data) and `target` is the actual label of the given image.

Furthermore, in the above example, check below lines:

```
output = model(data) # shape [1, 10]
init_pred = output.max(1, keepdim=True)[1] # get the index of the max log-probability

# If the initial prediction is wrong, don't bother attacking, just move on
if init_pred.item() != target.item():
   continue

# Calculate the loss
loss = F.nll_loss(output, target)
```

In the above code, only those `output-target` pairs are passed into `F.nll_loss` loss function, where the model is predicting correctly. In case, it is unable to predict the label correctly, then all the operations(including loss calculation) after that are skipped and it continues with the next example in the `test_loader`.

Comment: I did print out target, but it just gave me something like: "tensor([3])" I'm confused, if target is just the label, why does it have a .item() function? I think nll_loss is taking in an image and also a class object. Isn't that correct?

Comment: Since I am trying to generate my own target, I am wondering on what to feed into the nll_loss

Comment: `torch.Tensor.item()` is used to get a python number from a tensor containing a single value.